# How to calculate Transaction per sec(TPS) in apache flink using Java

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading from kafka stream using flink and now i want to calculate the transactions per sec(TPS). I have observed one of the ways to achieve this by using windowing concept in flink but not able get it yet. Can anyone help me regarding this. Thanks in advance for the help!!.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in metric that reports numRecordsOutPerSecond, which you could observe on the Kafka source operator (or any other operator). Perhaps that's all you need:

[image]

For a tutorial (and examples) for learning how to use Flink's windowing API, see the [introduction to windows](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/streaming_analytics.html#windows) in the Flink training course that's part of the documentation.